# Was the condensate pump in my air conditioner unit wired incorrectly?

Tags: wiring, hvac, circuit-breaker, pump, overflow

My condensate pump stopped working - I noticed because there was a lot of water coming out of the condensed drain.

I bought one brand new but when I disconnected the old one, I realized that the overflow wires were connected together, that means two wires coming out of the air conditioner unit, and the other two wires that come with the condensed pump, were all taped together.

My only theory about this is that the person who installed the old pump was trying to bypass the switch in order to prevent the unit from turning off in case the pump overflowed.

Is that correct? I wired the new one the same way and I would like to know if I did something wrong?

---

There isn’t exactly a diagram, because I am talking about the pump that was connected and the way it was connected, but if you are familiar with the condensate pump, you see some model has two wired, I can attach a diagram for one pump but my question is, why was my pump connected this way?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture or diagram of the wiring?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Providing the manufacturer name(s) and exact model numbers of your AC unit and condensate pump units will help tremendously. Also, providing picture(s) of exactly how you've got things wired now will help too. Once you've [edit]ed those into your original post, please spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] so you can learn how to get the best out of the site.